# Is there any way to run the model.applyEdits() in a separate Worker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, monaco-editor

I'm developing a collaborative editor using the monaco-editor, and because of the business model (CRDT), users editing a same document receive the data character by character, but this causes the model.applyEdits() to be called n*characters times, freezing the application until all edits are made. My question is, is there any way to run a separate Worker making calls from ITextModel?